# Basic Windows Server 2016 Install on VMWare Workstation - Need application with "localhost" url to be Accessible via the Host Machine

Tags: networking, windows-server-2016, vmware-workstation

**End Goal**
I'd like to give my test web application a URL that can be accessed from the host machine. The application is successfully installed on windows server 2016 and the windows server is intalled on a vm powered by VMWare workstation.

**My ask**

- I have yet to configure roles on my test windows server 2016 environment. Do I need to for my end goal?
- If so which roles need to be configured?
- If not what am I missing that's preventing my host system from accessing my application via the web?

**Existing Setup**
 - My test Server is on a bridged connection with a static ip address. 
 - Also the host machine & any other machine on the network fails to successfully ping the server.
 - The server however can successfully ping the host and any other cpu on my network. 
 - I can access my application successfully by navigating to localhost/ or even the ipaddress of my windows server (whichever i tell my application to point to).
 - But the issue is that I can't access that from the host machine.

Assistance is greatly appreciated! Feel free to ask for more info if necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Total firewall issue. Did some additional research, this time on the pinging issue saw people suggest that this is firewall related. Followed the steps [here](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln156432/windows-server-how-to-properly-turn-off-the-windows-firewall-in-windows-server-2008-and-above?lang=en) and turned off firewall in my server.

afterwards was able to ping successfully and access my web application from the host machine.